# i have a listview with mp3 list to download i want to download all the listview items one by one showing progressbar on each row

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

when i open list view activity i want to download all the `listview` items one by one without clicking the download button and showing progress for the particular item how can i implement this functionality?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);
            holder.progressBar= (CircleProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_day.setText(daysList.get(i));
        holder.tv_day.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Myriad-Pro_31655.ttf"));

        /*File cuteVideosDir = new File(context.getFilesDir()
                .getPath(), type);

        File[] files = cuteVideosDir.listFiles();
        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        list.clear();

        if (files!=null) {
            for (File singleFile : files) {

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(singleFile);
                String name = singleFile.getName();
                String path = singleFile.getPath();
                list.add(name);

            }
        }

        if (Utility.getSharedPreferencesBoolean(context,type))
        {
            if (list.contains(daysList.get(i)+".mp3"))
            {

                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {


                DownloadFileFromURL fileFromURL = new DownloadFileFromURL(context, holder.progressBar, audiolist.get(i), daysList.get(i), type);
                fileFromURL.execute();
            }
        }*/



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: see `DownloadManager` API docs

Comment: how to update each child progressbar

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: can you give me any sample link for that

Comment: google will give a lot of links